# home, end, delete, pageup, pagedown with ksh

Tags: shell, bind, ksh, key, openbsd

I want to use home, end, delete, pageup, pagedown with ksh. My TERM is 
xterm-color. These keys works fine with tcsh and zsh, but not with ksh 
(print a tilde ~)

I found this:

```
bind '^[[3'=prefix-2
bind '^[[3~'=delete-char-forward
bind '^[[1'=prefix-2
bind '^[[1~'=beginning-of-line
bind '^[[4'=prefix-2
bind '^[[4~'=end-of-line
```

But when I set one bindkey, the last does not work anymore.

How can I use these keys in ksh with a .kshrc ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the EDITOR or VISUAL variables set?  If not, that may be the way forward.

```
  EDITOR=vi
```

may be sufficient.

Comment: or `EDITOR=emacs`. Either way you can put that in your `~/.kshrc` file

Comment: Copied from *Nicolas*' comment incorrectly posted as an answer: "with  `EDITOR=vi` , home, end, delete, pageup, pagedown does not print a tilde ~ (but does not work). Moreover, I do not like vi EDITOR. On the other hand, with `EDITOR=emacs`, the problem is the same. These keys does not work, and print a tilde ~."

Answer (score 0):

You can start [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) with `-o emacs` or do `set -o emacs` on run-time within the shell, then issue `bind` to list the key bindings.

Other options for key bindings apart from [emacs](/questions/tagged/emacs)  are `gmacs` and `vi`.

Read more in: [ksh(1)](https://man.openbsd.org/ksh#set_2).